# Chrome Extension Authorization page could not be loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to authorize with Cognito in my Chrome Extension using chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow.

Manifest.JSON file

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "app",
"permissions": [
    "http://*/*", "tabs", "webNavigation", "activeTab", "storage", "identity",
    "declarativeContent", "https://****.eu-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize/*"
],
"version": "0.7.5",
"content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["src/content.js"],
    "matches": [
        "*://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/*"
    ]
}],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["src/backgroundOauth.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
},
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
    "scopes": [
        "openid", "email", "profile", "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
    ]
}
```

}

**BackgroundOauth.js**

```
    const URI = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL();
const CLIENT_ID = <CLIENT_ID>;
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        "url": "https://<secret>.auth.eu-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?" + CLIENT_ID +
            "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(URI) +
            "&response_type=code",
        'interactive': true,
    },
    function(redirect_url) {
        console.log(redirect_url);
    });
```

After install and run, output log 'Authorization page could not be loaded.'.

redirect_url inside of launchWebAuthFlow is undefined.

I have listed my cognito settings as well to see if it something wrong with Cognito setup instead of Chrome issue. Anyone who can help me on this I'll be extremely grateful.

[Image of my Cognito Pool settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iibXC.png)

Comment: Assuming the page works when you open it manually in a tab it sounds like a bug in Chrome. If that page has iframes (maybe used by third-party libraries), try removing them.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in another thread. Issue is missing `client_id=` key inside of query string

Fixed code:

```js
const URI = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL();
const CLIENT_ID = <CLIENT_ID>;
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
    "url": "https://<secret>.auth.eu-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize" +
        "?client_id=" + encodeURIComponent(CLIENT_ID) +
        "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(URI) +
        "&response_type=code",
    'interactive': true,
},
function(redirect_url) {
    console.log(redirect_url);
});
```

Relevant docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html